# Search in all dataset values in python

Tags: python, dataframe

I am trying to find a value in my dataset

I know we can do this

```
df.loc[df['name'].isin('john', 'tom')]
```

but can we do it differently to search all the columns and rows in a dataset to find these words

i tried that but did not work

```
df.iloc['john'.isin(df[:])]
```

any idea how to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just do `df[df.isin(['john', 'tom'])]`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([["John", "Adam", "Eve"], ["Eve", "Adam", "John"]])
df.isin(["John", "Eve"])
#       0      1     2
# 0  True  False  True
# 1  True  False  True
```

However the not selected values are filled with `NaN`:

```
df[df.isin(["John", "Eve"])]
#       0    1     2
# 0  John  NaN   Eve
# 1   Eve  NaN  John
```

But is still works as a mask:

```
df[df.isin(["John"])] = "john"
df
#       0     1     2
# 0  john  Adam   Eve
# 1   Eve  Adam  john
```

If you want to filter with `loc`, you need to reduce the dimensionality first:

```
df.loc[df.isin(["john", "Eve"]).any(axis=1)]
#       0     1     2
# 0  john  Adam   Eve
# 1   Eve  Adam  john

df = pd.DataFrame([["John", "Adam", "Eve"], ["Eve", "Adam", "Alice"]])
df.loc[df.isin(["John", "Eve", "Adam"]).all(axis=1)]
#       0     1    2
# 0  John  Adam  Eve
```

Comment: without using loc?

Comment: @asmgx: Yes, without `loc`. You can use `loc`, but you need to reduce it to one dimension first (using `any` or `all`). See edited answer.